Return max date where value is less than another value - ignoring certain filters - DAX
I have a table with example data below:



Master Project
project
date
Budget to Date
Actual to Date




X
A
Jan-24
200
300


X
A
Feb-24
600
500


X
A
Mar-24
1000
900


X
B
Jan-24
300
200


X
B
Feb-24
500
500


X
B
Mar-24
800
1200



I want to write a formula that I can put into a table or matrix that will find the max date where actual was greater than budget based on a slicer.  Example:
The user has selected Mar-24 in the slicer so the table is showing Mar-24 data for multiple projects.  For Project A I would want this formula to return Feb-24 because that is the max date where Budget to Date (600) was less than Actual to Date (900).  For Project B I would want it to show Mar-24 because Actuals in Mar-24 (1200) are greater than budget (800).  If the Matrix was collapsed Project X would show Mar-24 as the actuals for both projects (2100) are greater than the budget for both projects in Mar-24 (1800)
The desired result in a matrix expanded with a slicer on Mar-24:



Master Project
Project
Measure
Budget to Date
Actual To Date




X

Mar-24
1800
2100



A
Feb-24
1000
900



B
Mar-24
800
1200



The solution below works (provided by the first answer) when just 'Project' is in the matrix but does not work when trying to roll up to the 'Master Project' level.  I feel like there needs to be a sum() for the 'Budget to Date' but that is not allowed in DAX in the calculate filter.
Max_date =
  var curDate = MAX(table[date]) // get the current date in context
  var curActual = SUM(table[Actual to Date])
  var result =
    CALCULATE(
      MAX(table[date]),
      table[Budget to Date] < curActual,
      table[date] < curDate,
      REMOVEFILTERS(table[date]) // remove date context
    )
  return result


Can you share how your table output would look like after creating the new measure?

Updated!  Thank you for taking a look.  I know its a bit of an odd request but this is just one part of a larger formula I am working on.

Try the following expression:
Max_date = 
  var tbl = 
    SUMMARIZE(
      CALCULATETABLE(YourTable, YourTable[date] <= MAX(YourTable[date]), REMOVEFILTERS('YourTable'[date])),
      [date],
      "Actual", SUM(YourTable[Actual to Date]),
      "Budget", SUM(YourTable[Budget to Date])
    )
  var result = MAXX(FILTER(tbl, [Budget] < [Actual]), [date])
  return result

Note: Project A is Jan not Feb.


You know what, this works but I did mess up on a detail.  The measure is going to be used in a matrix that rolls up to the project level but there are additional sublevels that it needs to be calculated on.  Really the table I provided should have Project and Subproject.   So it cant just be table[budget to date], it needs to be sum of table[budget to date] but that is not allowed in calculate.  Do I need to add a filter somehow to accomplish this?  Thank you so much for your help, not sure why I didn't see your solution before.

Like if the table in the example above had another project column called Master Project with the value 'X' for all rows.  Both Master Project and Project were added to rows in the Matrix and the measure you posted was a value.  When expanded A would show Feb 24, B would show Mar-24, and at the top level of X it would show Mar-24 (Actuals in March for both programs 2100 > budget for both programs in March 1800)

Updated the question with a more thorough example!

Updated answer above.
